# SQL subquery partial match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to run a select that partial matches the results of another select. Nothing I do seems to produce what I want.

I have a value in a table that is a comma delimited list, so it will look like this.

```
List
-----------
item1,item2,item3
```

Then I have another table (lines) with a column that contains items 1-3 and others that I want to filter out. This is what I'm trying, but can't get it to work.

```
Select lineitems.itemnumber from lineitems,productlines
where productlines.list like concat('%',(select list from productlines),'%')
```

The result shows everything in lineitems.itemnumber and not just items 1-3.

Comment: Fix you data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string column.

Comment: I am, unfortunately, bound to this data model

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sorry, added it. It's MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
select li.itemnumber
from lineitems li
where exists (select 1
              from productlines pl
              where concat(',', pl.list, ',') like concat('%,', li.itemnumber,',%')
             );
```

This includes the delimiters, so you won't get false matches.

You can also use `string_split()`:

```
select li.itemnumber
from lineitems li
where exists (select 1
              from productlines pl cross apply
                   string_split(pl.list, ',') s
              where s.value = li.itemnumber,',%'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but in Postgres you can something like this:

```
select li.itemnumber
from lineitems li
  join productlines pl on li.item_id = any(string_to_array(pl.list, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's what you need.

```
SELECT lineitems.itemnumber 
FROM lineitems
WHERE EXISTS (  
    SELECT *
    FROM productlines
    WHERE productlines.list LIKE '%' + lineitems.itemnumber + '%'
)
```

Alternatively, you can `string_split` function like below (note that it may affect performance)

```
SELECT lineitems.itemnumber
FROM lineitems, productlines
WHERE EXISTS (  
    SELECT *
    FROM productlines
        CROSS APPLY string_split(productlines.list, ',') AS splitted_itemnumber
    WHERE splited_itemnumber.value = lineitems.itemnumber
)
```